# Why do we use RiverpodGenerator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

What is the point of using `RiverpodGenerator` or `Freezed` as I understand we could just do `CRUD operations` to implement our data using models. But why, when and how do we use `RiverpodGenerator`?

Comment: Most of this will be moot when macros enter the language.  You'll still need the annotations, but at least you won't have to worry about a separate build state because it'll be part of the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RiverpodGenerator and Freezed have completely different uses.

*If we are talking about RiverpodGenerator,* it solves some problems (compared to the classical definition):

- a clearer syntax based on classical functions
- pass as many parameters as needed + both positional and named parameters are available. In the past, we limited ourselves to the family
- stateful hot-reload of the code written in Riverpod

*If we're talking about Freezed,* it's for:

- easy and quick immutability of objects
- immediately overridden `hashcode/==`
- Matching in different styles

That said, it's very flexible right now. The modifier `@Freezed(...)` allows you to redefine almost completely the result of generation.

**All of this may soon fade into oblivion**. And to date, the developers of Dart are actively working on it.

Answer (score 2):

It just anout make it easier to implement the providers and reduce the error until producing the providers, it can save your time and make the development faster.
Maybe you will not know the feature of it until you work on a larger projects.